# toggle checkbox on row mouse click

Tags: wpf, checkbox

I have a DataGrid which has some text columns and a template column with a checkbox. I need to make this checkbox toggle when user clicks anywhere in that row. What is the best way to do it?

Right now I toggle the checkbox on selected item change and on cell mouse left button click event. But this has 2 problems.

First problem is the situation when DataGrid has just databound. First row gets selected. But when I do a cell click on it the DataRowCell.MouseLeftButtonDown event doesn't get raised for unknown reason. So the checkbox doesn't get toggled. Possible solution is to deselect the first row after the data binding.

Second problem is that the checkbox gets toggled twice when user clicks directly on the checkbox at another row. This results in checkbox being toggled twice, which means that the checked value doesn't change.

So what is the best way to implement the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding the checkbox's checked property to row isselected property? You haven't specified if the checked value is always off at default unless you click on it, if this is not the case you can try using an custom IValueConverter to toggle the values.

Comment: I need to let the checkbox be checked when the row is unselected, so this solution doesn't suit me.

Answer (score 0):

Set CheckBox.IsEnabled = false which prevented it from being toggled by user. Set the DataGrid to readonly which unfocused first row.